# Undefined class constant 'CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT'

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I upgraded magento from version 1.9.1.1 to 1.9.2.1. The checkout process always fails and redirects back to thee cart page. This is the Error I found in Apache's error log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT' in
/var/www/app/code/local/Lotusbreath/OneStepCheckout/Model/Type/Onepage.php 
on line 108, referer: http://www.websitename.com/onestepcheckout/
```

I thought the checkout extension was faulty, so I replaced it with the original Magento checkout template, the same error appears:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT' in 
/var/www/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php on line 653,
referer: http://www.website.com/checkout/onepage/
```

I checked both PHP files for the CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT and indeed, it's not defined there. Question is, this used to work fine before this. I am not sure if this update broke something or is it the recent patch fix I have applied. I tried reverting the patch but that didn't work either.

This is the snippet from the PHP file Onepage.php that contains the CHECK_USE stuff:

```
$data['checks'] = Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT
        | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY
        | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_USE_FOR_CURRENCY
        | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_ORDER_TOTAL_MIN_MAX
        | Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL;
```

Is this the reason payments are failing and redirecting back to the cart page? If so, how would I go about fixing this?

Comment: Are you sure the patch is appropriate for your edition.Because apparently this class doenst have that constant https://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Payment/Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract.html#sec-const-summary

Comment: Hi, Yes, I download the patch corresponding to the magento version I had. Later on, I downloaded and installed magento 1.9.2.1 which already has the latest patches included.

Comment: The `CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT` constant is part of `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`.  The error is being thrown as it tries to check against it.  Ensure Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php is in place and matches your downloaded and extracted verison.

Comment: Hey Douglas, thanks for the reply. Yes, file is in place. This was solved already. I will post how I got it solved in an answer. Thanks for dropping by!

Answer (score 0):

There is a probability that your core files were modified.

During upgrade core files will be overwritten which might result in some code (added due non standard coding ) getting removed.

So if you do have a backup then search for the missing define and file that had that.

@Had a look at your input.
Placing a file in local will result in core file override.
This is not a Magenton standard approach, developer should have extended that class and modified or added some specific function.

I suggest that you should make sure that all files in local Mage folder should be removed by some extended module.

Comment: I know that local files will override the cores. It wasn't me who added the local file. I reckon it was an extension. Anyway, everything is good now. So, I consider this solved :) Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I know few Module providers do this not standard stuff.Which breaks things later.So when selecting a module make sure that this standard is in place.Goof know you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message was referencing this class Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract. I checked it at the core file located at: app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php. This file had the following snippet within the Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract class:

```
/**
 * Bit masks to specify different payment method checks.
 * @see Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract::isApplicableToQuote
 */
const CHECK_USE_FOR_COUNTRY       = 1;
const CHECK_USE_FOR_CURRENCY      = 2;
const CHECK_USE_CHECKOUT          = 4;
const CHECK_USE_FOR_MULTISHIPPING = 8;
const CHECK_USE_INTERNAL          = 16;
const CHECK_ORDER_TOTAL_MIN_MAX   = 32;
const CHECK_RECURRING_PROFILES    = 64;
const CHECK_ZERO_TOTAL            = 128;
```

Now, there was another Abstract.php file located at the local pool at: app/code/local/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php. Notice the (core) and (local) difference in the path.

This file in the local pool didn't have the snippet shown above. The file also had some few other differences. So, what I did was, I made a backup of the Abstract.php file at the local pool. Then copied the Abstract file from the core to the local pool. Everything started working again.